# Point/Redirect subdirectory to a different folder using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am using apache server for managing my server. Is there any way to point

1. xyz.com/blog to folder /public_html/blog/
2. xyz.com to folder /public_html/xyz/

Thanks.

Comment: What is your folder structure and URL? What does `www`  represent. That's probably something best done updating your apache config and changing the document_root than doing redirect. .htaccess is not suited for everything versus a proper set.

Comment: How can I do it using apache config?

Comment: What's your current `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: It's /public_html

I have a xyz.com/beta pointing to public_html/beta
and xyz.com/blog pointing to public_html/blog

Answer (score 0):

You can try these rules in `/public_html/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(blog|beta)(/.*)?$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule !^xyz/ xyx%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: what is this line for  - RewriteRule ^(blog|beta)(/.*)?$ - [L,NC] ?

I don't have a beta folder now.

Comment: You wrote about beta in comments above. This rule is for skipping blog and beta paths from rules below.

Comment: Thanks anubhava.  Will it point xyz.com/blog to public_html/blog folder?

Comment: Yes that's what the intent of first rule. Did you test these rules?